# Spring Statemachine: how to handle two transitions that has the same source state?

Tags: spring-statemachine

How does Spring Statemachine handle two transitions that has the same source state?

For example:

- Source State: ready
- Event: start
- One transition will be lead to the target state `running`, another one will be `failure`

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you described above can be achieved in two ways.

In case of failure to process the incoming event (`Start`), machine would remain in the original state (`ready`). The transition is only completed when event is process successfully.

However, if you really need to get away from `ready` state and move to `running` or `failure`, one can use the [Guard condition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#configuring-guards). You can use an evaluation function to define if the `Start` event was successful or not and define to which state machine should go to.

This can be achieved using a [Choice pseudo-state](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#choice-state) that is protected by a Guard class, based on machine configuration and Guard evaluation, machine would move to the expected state

[The official doc for reference on how to make the implementation is here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#sm-guards)